# When clicking on a button a new contentView is made

Tags: android, android-button

I am following the book I am reading, and trying to apply it to what I want to do.
I have a button set up, yes it works, but when I click it, a blank screen is displayed.
Here is my code:

```
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View volButton = findViewById(R.id.volButton);
        volButton.setOnClickListener(this); 
   } 

    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent i;
        switch (v.getId()) {
           case R.id.volButton:
              i = new Intent(this, VolumeControl.class);
              startActivity(i);
              break;
        }
     }
```

Volume Control Class

```
public class VolumeControl extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "This is the Toast message", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

The toast window shows up, but a blank screen in made.

If I add setContentView(R.layout.main); after the super.onCreate, it re-draws the main screen. How can I use this setup without having to redraw anything? I dont want to have all my code in the switch statement in my main class, it would look way too sloppy.

Comment: what you want to do on click of a button, if you are trying to load a new activity on click of the button then u will get the blank screen because you are not setting any lay out for the volume control activity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Activity class takes care of creating a window for you in which you can place your UI with setContentView(View). Since you are creating a new Intent that is the VolumeControl, then your are focusing in the "window" of the created VolumeControl. If you want the original window to be visible when you click the button, then in your android manifest, change the android theme of the activity.

example:

```
    <activity
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:name=".VolumeControl"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
        <intent-filter >
            <action android:name="my.package.NAME" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Comment: I don't know if this is bad to do, but I changed android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog" to android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoDisplay" and it works the way I want. :)

Comment: I forgot to mention try using different themes that will achieve what you want. :)

Comment: So doing this isn't a bad habit, or a dirty way to code applications? (buttons in specific)

Answer (score 0):

This is what you are doing:

1. I think a setContentView is missing from your first Activity, so I'm assuming you have it there
2. when the button is pressed
3. a new intent is created
4. VolumeControl is started with this intent
5. VolumeControl shows the Toast
6. then waits
7. because you haven't set any layout, a black screen is show

Then if you do setContentLayout(R.layout.main) the same layout as the first Activity is displayed, though it's now VolumeControl.
So, if you want to display something different use a different layout.